# Netgear Router Throttling Bandwidth

Tags: internet, wireless-router, bandwidth

I have a Netgear WNDR3700v4 wireless gigabit router.  I've tested my internet connect speed directly through my modem via speedtest.net at just over 120 Mbps.  While testing through my router (wireless) it drops to under 20 Mbps.

What would cause this much loss?

I used this router at another location with a 50 Mbps connection and it tested at around that speed directly to the modem or through the router.  I don't think I've made any changes to the configuration during the move.

I'm really stumped.  Any ideas?

UPDATE 1:
Per a suggested comment I dabbled in modifying the channel used by the wireless router.  I used a Wifi Analyzer app that allowed me to see the channels being used by nearby wireless networks.  After trying several "free" channels I am still unsuccessful in increasing my speed.  Any other suggestions are welcome.  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 2:
I just used the speedtest.net app on a tablet device and the speed is considerably quicker than seen on my laptop - I tested on several devices and the laptop is the only slow device.

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
- Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)

UPDATE 3:
I ran an update and restarted the computer and the connection jumped up considerably.  It's still a bit slow (30 Mbps) but much better than the 5 Mpbs I was seeing before the restart.

Comment: This sounds like wireless interference to me. Have you tried a different WiFi channel?

Comment: I haven't tried another channel.  I'll be sure to try that.  Thanks!

Comment: I got a network analyzer and found a channel that was not as commonly used but I am still unable to increase my speed.